# Laravel user update problems

Tags: laravel, authentication

Will try make this clear as much as I can.

Im rolled out a make Auth call in order to use the login and registeration function of laravel and later just used the template to provide the needs I wanted that is.

1. If user is admin he/she can register a new user.

   ```
   public function openNewUser(){
   return view('auth.register');
   ```

   }

   NB. Part for update.

   ```
   public function registerNewUser(Request $request){
           $this->validate($request,[
               'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
               'name' => 'required|max:120',
               'password' => 'required|min:4|confirmed']);

           $user = new User();

           $user->name = $request->name;
           $user->email = $request->email;
           $user->password = encrypt($request->password);

           if (Gate::denies('register-user')) {
               return redirect()->back();
           }

           $user->save();
           return view('home');
     }
   ```

   2. Problem 1 - I also want to update user , which is giving problems. The password inputs return empty fields , which i understand. When I try to change it doenst work the confirm password always give a mismatch even though they are the same. When I leave it blank too it doesnt work because the field is required to be filled. I took them off the form and tried if i could edit the email only but only didnt work.

public function userUpdate (Request $request,$user_id) {

```
  $this->validate($request,[
      'email' => 'required|email',
      'name' => 'required|max:120',
      'password' => 'required|min:4|confirmed']);
       $user = new User();
         $user->name = $request->name;
         $user->email = $request->email;
         $user->password = encrypt($request->password);

    if (Gate::allows('register-user')) {
          $user->save();

        $user->roles()->attach($request->roles);
        return redirect()->route('view_users');
    }elseif (Gate::denies('register-user')) {
        if (Auth::id() == $user_id) {
            $user->save();

            $user->roles()->attach($request->roles);
            return redirect()->route('view_users');
        }else{
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }

}
```

Problem 2. I just realized all logins I am doing with my new registration gives These credentials do not match our records.Even though the credentials are there and was registered correctly.
I am using the login provided by laravel but I created my own registration.

Please how can I edit and update my users and also be able to login after registration

Comment: Wild guess: Is it possible you changed your application key in the meantime (`php artisan key:generate`) ?

Comment: @dbr no I didnt change the key, everything seems to look fine and should work right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong , Since I am using Laravel's login my registration had to use bycrypt for the encryption which is what Laravel registration was using  , but I was using encrypt when I created my own registration so there was a conflict when logging in. (Remembere I was using Laravels login not my own written Login). I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

What version of Laravel are you using?

Here is my (v5.3) `register()` method in `RegisterController.php`, at least part for registration:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{   
...
// save and login user
$user = $this->create($request->all());
$this->guard()->login($user);
...
}
...
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
        'phone' => $data['phone'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

and the `login()` method from `LoginController.php`

```
public function login(Request $request) 
{
$credentials = $this->credentials($request);
...
if ($this->guard()->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
      return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
   }
}
```

Hopefully I haven't miss anything.
Keep in mind that things have changed here from version 5.2.

Comment: although Im creating my own user I am using Laravels auth to login so I am actually not writing my own Login code.

________
But the strange thing that is happening before I wrote register code I registered  a user with Laravels registration method. After I changed my codes I can still login with the user I created first but all Users I created using my code is being registered in the database but I cant login with them